# How to deactivate maintenance mode from wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have deactivated all plugins and then activate it back then maintenance mode got enabled by itself.

FYI there is no .maintenance file in my root directory, but there is one plugin in plugins directory.
I also have tried by renaming the maintenance plugin but still getting maintenance mode message.

One more the previous developer have used custom maintenance mode page.

Comment: Please explain further. From above i guess maintenance mode might be coming from index.php inside wp-content/themes/<your-theme>/index.php or index.html

Comment: ...or *functions.php*...or *header.php*...This question is way too broad.

Comment: because of maintenance mode on i can't able to open dashboard.whenever i try to open it by  "domain/wp-admin" it redirect me to custom maintenance page.

Comment: Have you seen the error like "Briefly unavailable for scheduled maintenance. Check back in a minute."? If yes then you can seen the file name like ".maintenance" on root in Wordpress. Delete that file and check your site is working again.

Answer (score -1):

I came across the same issue over and over again especially if you update your current theme, check out the steps [here](http://www.panayiotisgeorgiou.net/fix-briefly-unavailable-scheduled-maintenance-wordpress/) that resolved this issue.

To summarize: When WordPress is doing any updates, it creates a *.maintenance* file in the root directory of the installation. The file should be automatically removed when the update is completed. If it isn't removed, or something goes wrong and the process dies without cleaning up, going in and manually deleting the *.maintenance* file will get things moving again.